# Shortening an Excel formula if possible

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, database, microsoft-excel-2013

I am unable to shorten an Excel formula I am using in an Excel database. I've googled it, but this appears to be already the shortest way from the first page on Google.

> =COUNTIF(K:K,"Busy")+COUNTIF(K:K,"Hangup")+COUNTIF(K:K,"Stopped")+COUNTIF(K:K,"Voicemail")+COUNTIF(K:K,"Wrong Number")+COUNTIF(K:K,"No Answer")+COUNTIF(K:K,"IP Phone Offline")+COUNTIF(K:K,"Call accepted")

The formula isn't pretty and, on the report I need to produce about this database, it stands out as looking quite simply horrible.

Can anyone give me a pointer in the right syntax OR send through the correct way to do this but annotated so I can learn how to do it in the future?

Thanks!

Edd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(K:K,{"Busy","Hang up","Stopped","Voicemail","Wrong Number","No Answer","IP Phone Offline","Call accepted"}))
```

If this list is subject to change/expansion then it would make more sense to store the criteria in cells within the worksheet, rather than within the formula itself. For example, if the criteria were in A1:A8, the required formula would be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(K:K,A1:A8))
```

Regards

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The top one answer helps a lot as the criteria is around 500 rows of a few thousand row spreadsheet. Thanks again! I'd upvote it but unfortunately I have less than 15 reputation!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to make it look good.

1) Go to **Formulas** tab - under **Defined names** group - select **Name manager** (Or for old versions of excel using menus - Insert>Name>Define) and in the "Names" box type: calldetails.

2) Scope - can be workbook.

3) Now click in the "Refers to" box and type (or paste): `=COUNTIF(K:K,"Busy")+COUNTIF(K:K,"Hang up")+COUNTIF(K:K,"Stopped")+COUNTIF(K:K,"Voicemail")+COUNTIF(K:K,"Wrong Number")+COUNTIF(K:K,"No Answer")+COUNTIF(K:K,"IP Phone Offline")+COUNTIF(K:K,"Call accepted")`  then click Add.

Now anywhere you want to use this formula just type `=calldetails`

This makes it look neat and tidy

Comment: Thank you very much for the help here, I would up vote this if I had the reputation to do so! The problem with this one is the formula has to be explained, so it would still look a bit messy in the report! However, I shall still incorporate that into the spreadsheet for myself, saves the eyesore!

Comment: Never mind .. upvote when you have the reputations.... The answer from @XOR LX is perfect.... Kudos